# SQL query to produce XML result

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am trying to produce the following XML when querying a database. The database
contains two tables COUNTRY and STATES -

```
 <Country>
   <CountryInfo>
       <name>USA</name>
       <districts>50</districts>
       <state>
           <stateName>New York</stateName>
           <statePop>8,244,910</statePop>
       </state>
       <state>
           <stateName>Chicago</stateName>
           <statePop>State Population: 2,707,120</statePop>
       </state>
 </CountryInfo>
 <CountryInfo>
       <name>Germany</name>
       <districts>16</districts>
       <state>
           <stateName>Berlin</stateName>
           <statePop>3,469,910</statePop>
       </state>
       <state>
           <stateName>Brandenburg</stateName>
           <statePop>2,500,000</statePop>
       </state> 
   </CountryInfo>
 </Country>
```

Here is an attempt -

```
 select ctry.NAME, ctry.DISTRICTS, st.ST_NAME, st.ST_POPULATION
 from COUNTRY ctry inner join STATES st on (ctry.NAME=st.COUNTRY);
```

The result is a flat file.

```
 <CountryCollection>
   <COUNTRY>
     <NAME>USA</NAME>
     <DISTRICTS>50</DISTRICTS>
     <ST_NAME>New York</ST_NAME>
     <ST_POPULATION>8,244,910</ST_POPULATION>
   </COUNTRY>
   <COUNTRY>
     <NAME>USA</NAME>
     <DISTRICTS>50</DISTRICTS>
     <ST_NAME>CHICAGO</ST_NAME>
     <ST_POPULATION> 2,707,120</ST_POPULATION>
   </COUNTRY>
   <COUNTRY>
     <NAME>GERMANY</NAME>
     <DISTRICTS>16</DISTRICTS>
     <ST_NAME>Berlin</ST_NAME>
     <ST_POPULATION>3,469,910</ST_POPULATION>
   </COUNTRY>
   <COUNTRY>
     <NAME>GERMANY</NAME>
     <DISTRICTS>50</DISTRICTS>
     <ST_NAME>Brandenburg</ST_NAME>
     <ST_POPULATION>2,500,000</ST_POPULATION>
   </COUNTRY>
 </CountryCollection>
```

How could I group them to get the desired result?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a oracle RDBMS try this.

```
SELECT XMLElement("Country" 
  , XMLAgg(
    XMLElement("CountryInfo"
      ,XMLFOREST(CTRY.NAME "name", ctry.DISTRICTS "districts") 
      , xmlAgg(
        XMLElement("state",XMLFOREST(st.ST_NAME "stateName", st.ST_POPULATION  "statePop") 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
FROM COUNTRY ctry
INNER JOIN STATES st
ON (ctry.NAME=st.COUNTRY)
GROUP BY CTRY.NAME ,ctry.DISTRICTS
```

Edited to apply correction by @A.B.Cade.

Comment: It says "table or view does not exist." The XMLAgg does become bold like XMLElement or XMLForest. Could it be that XMLAgg does not exist?

Comment: What is your database version? I Tested it on 11gR2 with a similar structure.

Comment: @proximityFlying, xmlagg is not table or view but an aggregative function, maybe the names of the tables aren't exactly the same? because the query works (only needs `,ctry.DISTRICTS` in the group by clause) here is a sqlfiddle demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/26cd6/3